# When is a class variable initialized in Python?

Tags: python, class, static, initialization

Consider the following Python 3 code:

```
class A:
    b = LongRunningFunctionWithSideEffects()
```

When will `LongRunningFunctionWithSideEffects()` be called? At the moment the module is imported? Or at the moment the class is first used in some way?

Comment: I highly suggest reading throught the [Python class documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). The class-based OOP of Python is similar but different enough from C++ for there to be many areas where things are not working as you think they *should*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the moment the module is imported

`test.py`:

```
def x():
    print('x')

class A:
    x = x()
```

then

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
x
```

Answer (score 8):

The code inside a class runs when the `class` statement is encountered - ie. during the import itself.

This is because, unlike in Java or C# class definitions, Python `class` statements are actually executable code.

```
class A:
  print("I'm running!") # yup, code outside a method or field assignment!
  b = print("Me too!")

print("Wait for me!")
```

The result is neatly in order of execution:

```
I'm running!
Me too!
Wait for me!
```

Comment: I beleive it is the same in Java as well. Static variables initialized at the time of class loader.

Answer (score 3):

It is done at the time of import. These are called static variables and are defined at the class level. These variables are created 1 per class and NOT 1 per object. They are part of loading the class which happens at the time of import.

Following is an example:

classA.py

```
class A:
    print("Printing before Static Variable Creation")
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self):
        instance_var = 2
```

main.py

```
from classA import A
```

Printing before Static Variable Creation

```
print('Printing Class Variable Value : ',A.class_var)
```

Printing Class Variable Value :  1

```
print(A.__dict__)
```

{'**module**': 'classA',
              ***'class_var': 1,***
              '**init**': function classA.A.**init**(self),
              '**dict**': attribute '**dict**' of 'A' objects,
              '**weakref**': attribute '**weakref**' of 'A' objects,
              '**doc**': None}